# Conceptual Help Affecting Set of Integers Rate of Change

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to figure out an algorithm to provide recommendations to an end user with no luck so far. A user will have a list of items with up to 100 items in it. Each item is assigned a number of points between 1 and 100, but the sum of all items always has to equal 100 points. Each item also has a priority associated with it (low, medium, high). When a new item is added to the list, all of the existing items points must be reallocated, along with the new item's points, to sum up to 100. The user is given three reallocation recommendations, one for each possible priority.

Scenario - assume a list with two items, both at medium priority and 50 points each. Before a third item is added, 3 recommendations are made. So for example,

> Low Recommendation - 40/40 + 10
>
> Med Recommendation - 33/33 + 34
>
> High Recommendation - 25/25 + 50

How would one even approach starting to write an algorithm without an overly complex for loop with if statements littered everywhere? It seems as though there is a simpler answer. Possibly with multipliers assigned to the priorities to increase/decrease the negative rate of change for the rest of the items points?

Generalized Example of Progression:

Text

```
                        T1  T2  T3  T4  T5
    Item 1              100 60  35  32  25
    Priority (Item 1)   3   3   3   3   3
    Item 2                  40  30  25  15
    Priority (Item 2)       2   2   2   2
    Item 3                      35  33  25
    Priority (Item 3)           3   3   3
    Item 4                          10  10
    Priority (Item 4)               1   1
    Item 5                              25
    Priority (Item 5)                   3
    TOTALS              100 100 100 100 100
```

Excel Screenshot
[image: Overly Generalized Example]

Comment: Who will assign the points and priorities to the items, will there be any kind of calculation and/or what is the condition other than the sum of item points being 100?

Comment: The user reallocates the points and assigns the new items priority by selecting one of the three priority recommendations.

So given two items at a medium priority and 50/50 points. When a third item is added the user is presented with 3 options.

Low could be 40/40 + 20 for the new item.
Medium would be 33/33 + 34 for the new item.
High would be 25/25 + 50 for the new item.

The priority of existing items is retained and used in the calculations for reallocation recommendations.

Comment: OK, and who is deciding how many Ts a new item is corresponded with? Your **Item 1** is only one row, but **Item 5** is 5 rows. Will a new **Item 6** will be 6 rows?

Comment: At T1, there is only 1 item in the list with an assigned priority of 3. At T2 there are now 2 items in the list, Item 1 and Item 2. Each T column indicates the items in the list at a specific point in time. Its intended to show the lists progression of how the allocation changes each time an additional item is added to the list. Item 6 would have 6 rows. One for each existing item and one for the new item. Perhaps there's a better way to illustrate this?

Comment: First, the priority should not be repeated in each column but s/b given as a value for each row (as shown on the screenshot). Then we can create a formula taking into the priority and item count into consideration. The formula of M2 in attached picture is `=ROUND(100/SUM($L$2:OFFSET($L$2;M$1-1;0))*$L2; 0)` and can be copied down or right. My formula misses a main point that rounding causes the sum smaller or bigger than 100, which might be resolved by a more complex formula. You might want to play around these and try to find a better solution. [excel screenshot](https://imgur.com/XPC2F1j)